# Uppercase letter for 'letztes'?

Tags: spelling, capitalization

Please have a look to this sentence:

> Nach dem Spiel wird Norbert klar, dass es sein letztes war.

My teacher marked *letztes* and said that *Letztes* is correct. Nevertheless, I think *letztes* is pointing to *Spiel* and therefore written in lowercase.

Who do you think is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it short: You are right, your teacher is wrong. Also your argument (it points to »Spiel«) is correct.

This is the official document for German orthography:
http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf

Read § 58 on page 64.

One of the example sentences is:

> Es waren neun Teilnehmer erschienen, auf den **zehnten** wartete man vergebens.